# confused about initWithCoder and custom UIViews

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm trying to create a custom `UIView` that brings in it's view from a nib file.

In my controller I have something like:

```
self.arcView=[[JtView alloc] initWithCoder:self];
self.arcView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
self.arcView.frame=CGRectMake(30.0f,200.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
[self.view addSubview:self.arcView];
```

My first question is what should go into the argument for `initWithCoder (NSCoder *)`? I tried self but got an incompatible pointer type but this seemed to work.  But on to question #2:

Second, the argument is that you use `initWithCoder` with `nibs` and `initWithFrame` when putting your custom view in a frame. Well, I want to load a `nib` in my custom view and then put it into  a frame. Can I just add a frame as above and it's ok (it looks like it works)?

Comment: Take a look here please and see the code sample stackoverflow.com/a/17798646/381807 – nesimtunc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it the other way around: it's not you who should call `initWithCoder:`, it's the implementation of the `loadNibNamed:owner:` method that does it.

What you need to do in your code is calling

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"theNIB" 
                                              owner:self 
                                            options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This would unbundle the NIB, and call your `initWithCoder:` initializer, and give you back a view with all the outlets connected.

Comment: Doesn't this method return an `NSArray` of all the top level objects in the NIB?  What if the `UIView` is not first?

Comment: thx, working through this right now. I've asked another question (sorry for spamming but feel like I have to understand this).

Answer (score 9):

`initWithCoder` is called much before `init` and `viewDidLoad` methods. And you never call it. It gets called as you load a nib file from your `mainBundle`.

However, It receives `NSCoder` as an argument. Check how it is called in a class:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self baseClassInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)baseClassInit {

    //initialize all ivars and properties    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.arcView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JtView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.arcView.frame = CGRectMake(30.0f,200.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
self.arcView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.arcView];
```

That will work and don't call `initWithCoder:`.

Answer (score 1):

Never call initWithCoder explicitly, it gets call implicitly while unarchiving archived object and initialise object ivars and properties- Archive object can be your custom model class saved in persistence storage or a custom view loaded from xib file.

In your class it's look like you are trying to create a custom view, so load it from xib file, for reference @dasblinkenlight code is a perfect solution.